# stream_socket_sendto() error when trying to upload a pdf file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error when uploading a pdf file, any ideas?:

> RuntimeException stream_socket_sendto(): A request to send or receive
>   data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when
>   sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was
>   supplied

**form in view:**

```
<form action="{{ route('press-files.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="pressFiles[]" multiple="multiple">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
    <i class="pe-upload"></i>
    <span>Start upload</span>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $press_files = $request->all();
    dd($press_files);
}
```

this is only happening on .pdf files - png's and jpegs all work.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be due to file size. I will keep this question and answer incase anybody else requires it.

The .pdf I was using was 2.8 MB and this failed, I used a much smaller file ~125kb and this worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines in your `.htaccess`

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M

php_value post_max_size 30M

php_value max_execution_time 300

php_value max_input_time 300
```